# admin can do everything [rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am implementing a User modeling for my app. That only current user can update and destroy his account I put in the user controller:

```
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

But now I also want that the admin can do those actions (well he can actually do everything)

I proposed to create another function in the helper admin_user to allow him the access to all actions then call it in the user controller like:

```
before_action :admin_user
```

but it seems like he is ignoring it. Any mathematic function to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just define that `correct_user` always returns immediately if the `current_user` is an admin:

```
def correct_user
  return if current_user.admin?

  # put existing logic here
end
```

Comment: In this case only admins can do update and delete users. what about if a normal user want to access these two actions too?

Comment: If you have complex logic behind this, you might want to look into a Gem that handles these things such as [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Comment: Thanks I got it now +1